# Getting unauthorized_error when using OAuth2.0

Tags: support, authentication, oauth2

I want to create a simple desktop application which connects to my account and shows some information in the status bar. I've been trying to authenticate using OAuth2.0 but I'm getting stuck and I cannot see what I´m doing wrong.

The steps I've followed are:

1. I've registered my application.
2. Checked the option "Enable Client Side OAuth Flow".
3. Call:

   ```
   https://stackexchange.com/oauth?client_id=997&scope=read_inbox,private_info&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success
   ```
4. I authenticate using my Google account and grant access.

From what I understood after reading the documentation is that I should get a redirect to this URL:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success
```

with my token in the query string.

Instead, I'm getting this:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success?error=unauthorized_client&error_description=This+application+has+been+registered+for+implicit+grants%2c+and+cannot+requests+codes
```

This is the error message:

> This application has been registered for implicit grants, and cannot requests codes

I've tried several scope options with the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [implicit flow](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) uses the url `https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog`, not `https://stackexchange.com/oauth`.

You should just need to change the url, otherwise that looks correct.

Answer (score 7):

The fix for me was unchecking "Enable Client Side OAuth Flow"